# Identify LEGO set with black door, large sand arch, dark-sand bricks, and tan plates?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

What does this build? It has a black door, large sand arch, dark-sand bricks, and tan plates.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THese parts come from [10232 Palace Cinema](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=10232-1), based on the black door and the two 8x8 wedge plates in Tan.

[image]